# How to get isolated scope of a directive with ngrepeat and two way bind?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

How we can get particular isolated scope of the directive while calling link function from controller(parent)?

I am having a directive and repeating it using ng-repeat. Whenever a button in the directive template is clicked it will call a function- Stop() in directive controller which in-turn calls function test() in parent controller, inside test() it will call a method dirSample () in directive's link function.

When I print the scope inside dirSample(), it prints the scope of the last created directive not the one which called it.

How can I get the scope of the directive which called it?

Find the pluker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wZarxBsgaiSNv3Sxp1LQ?p=preview)

```
.directive('stopwatch', function() { 
return {
restrict: 'AE',
scope: {
meri : '&',
control: '='
},
templateUrl: 'text.html',
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
scope.internalControl = scope.control || {};
scope.internalControl.dirSample = function(){
console.log(scope)
console.log(element)
console.log(attrs)
console.log(ctrl)
}
},
controllerAs: 'swctrl',
controller: function($scope, $interval) 
{
var self = this;
self.stop = function() 
{
console.log($scope)
$scope.meri(1)
};
}
}});
```

full code in plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the binding of your function from `&` to `=` since you need to pass a parameter. This means some syntax changes are in order, and also you need to pass the scope along the chain if you want to have it all the way at the end:

**HTML:**

```
<div stopwatch control="dashControl" meri="test"></div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.test = function(scope)
{
   console.log(scope);
   $scope.dashControl.dirSample(scope);
}
```

**Directive:**

```
.directive('stopwatch', function() { 

  return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  scope: {
    meri : '=',
    control: '='
  },

  templateUrl: 'text.html',

  link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

    scope.internalControl = scope.control || {};
    scope.internalControl.dirSample = function(_scope){
      console.log(_scope);

    }
  },
  controllerAs: 'swctrl',
  controller: function($scope, $interval) 
  {
    var self = this;
    self.stop = function() 
    {
      console.log($scope);
      $scope.meri($scope);
    };
  }
}});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ApEZHGfl3CCf3OQS7cui?p=preview)